# duplicate results on query for pair-wise relationships between rows for a SQL Server table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I work creating a database of merchants traders in the Atlantic at the end of the fifteen century. I wrote this query to find the relationships of individuals in the same contracts. It works fine, but It is creating duplicate results in the sense that will give for example; 'a,b,01-01-1500' and 'b,a,01-01-1500'. For me, it is a problem since I am not considering directionality at this point. I tried to simply filter the results but it created a more significant problem, as it just left one result regardless if the association had happened on a different date or a different contract (which granted was probably my fault, filtering is something I am still learning)

What would be a way to avoid this issue?

```
SELECT d1.gen_id as 'source',
d2.gen_id as 'target',
        c.date as 'timestamp'
from (
Select * from deed_party1
    ) as d1
    INNER JOIN
    (
    select * from deed_party1
    ) as d2
    on d1.deed_id = d2.deed_id
inner join contracts as c
on d1.deed_id = c.id
where d1.gen_id != d2.gen_id AND c.date between '1500-01-01' AND '1509-12-31';
```

Thanks for reading and your help,

Comment: Sql server table?

Answer (score 0):

You simply want `<` rather than `!=`.  But the subqueries are not necessary, so:

```
select d1.gen_id as source, d2.gen_id as target,
       c.date as timestamp
from deed_party1 d1 join
     deed_party1 d2
     on d1.deed_id = d2.deed_id and
        d1.gen_id < d2.gen_id join
     contracts c
     on d1.deed_id = c.id
where c.date between '1500-01-01' AND '1509-12-31';
```

Also:

- Do not unnecessarily use subqueries.  In most databases, this just clutters the query unnecessarily.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries, so subqueries can have a (negative) performance impact as well.
- Do not use single quotes to delimit column names.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.
- If you must escape column names, use backticks.
- Do not choose names that are already used by SQL, such as `timestamp`.  This is safe in MySQL, but just a bad practice.